# Is there any way to do 3D (Voxel Data) feature detection?

Tags: image-processing, 3d, feature-detection

In the 2D image processing, there are ways to find and match features of the image (like corner of the edges). However, I could not find the equivalent of that in the 3D-voxel data (Here voxel means a 3D grid with a gradation of values allocated to each box).
So, Is there any algorithm for 3D voxel feature matching?

Answer (score 1):

I never personally tried it but using image registration algorithm on Voxel Data you may have some results by trying registration on sub-cluster of voxel.
I would be interested in any feedback about this idea。